# Cloud Function to retrieve data from Reatime Database and create new table

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm developing an app using Firebase. Basically my Database is structured in this way. There is a node, called "Posts", which contains children of all posts. I would like to get my posts, sort them by their upvotes and create a new node in the firebase called "Charts" which contains the best 50 videos in a map. 
I tried developing the cloud function in Typescript but it doesn't work.

First of all when I try deploying it using firebase.database it says that "firebase cannot be found". If I use admin.firebase it deploys correctly but nothing actually works.

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require ('firebase-admin'); 
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

let map = new Map();

exports.updatePosts = firebase.database().ref("/Posts/Vl8J4kQk6dOXGxVbzgvCxir4MYW2").onUpdate((change,event) => {
const query = admin.database().ref("Posts/Vl8J4kQk6dOXGxVbzgvCxir4MYW2");

query.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
snapshot.forEach(child => {
let postID = child.key; 
let upvotes = child.nUpvotes; 
map.set(postID,upvotes);

});

});

return admin.database().ref("Charts").set(map);

});
```

Comment: It's saying "firebase cannot be found" because you're using an identifier called "firebase" that you didn't previously define.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks! Is the rest of the code good or are there other problems? I don't know if at this point it is better to handle this charts thing with a cloud function or by the app itself creating a query in an activity, but I'm afraid that if the number of posts increases a lot that might impact performances